# Show the True Type Font image in Combobox instead of the name

Tags: vb.net

Reference answer of @Plutonix on this link
[3D array loop and get the first dimension value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917121/3d-array-loop-and-get-the-first-dimension-value)

The class I'm adapting to show the TTF image on the combobox

```
Public Class FontItem
    Public Property TTImageFile As Image
    Public Property TTFile As String
    Public Property TTBoldFile As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Sub New(i as Image, f As String, b As String, n As String)
        TTImageFile = i
        TTFile = f
        TTBoldFile = b
        Name = n
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Using this code this way

```
    Dim myFonts As New List(Of FontItem)

    Dim data = {{My.Resources.arial, "Arial", "arial.ttf", "arialbd.ttf"},
        {My.Resources.courier, "Courier New", "cour.ttf", "courbd.ttf"},
        {My.Resources.verdana, "Verdana", "verdana.ttf", "verdanab.ttf"}}

    For n As Int32 = 0 To data.GetUpperBound(0)
        myFonts.Add(New FontItem(data(n, 0), data(n, 1), data(n, 2), data(n, 3)))
    Next

    AvialableFontsCombobox.DataSource = myFonts.ToArray()
```

Where "My.Resources.arial" and the others are the png file of the font preview

The code works fine but my AvialableFontsCombobox only show "arial.png", "courier.png"... as string instead of the graphic file.

And adding

```
    With AvialableFontsCombobox 
        .DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable
    End With
```

I only get blank spaces.

**What I'm missing? Do I need to do something more on??**

```
Private Sub AvialableFontsCombobox _DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles AvialableFontsCombobox .DrawItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a `Combo-` or `ListBox` to `OwnerDraw` you are saying that you will handle the drawing of the items - that means adding code to the `DrawItem` event.  In this case it appears that you want to draw some PNG images for each.  An alternative would be to draw the name of each font (or sample text) in that Font. The image approach is probably easier because you can be sure that each image is exactly the same size even if that means a little more white space on some.

First some setup things:

**Turn `Option Strict On`**. You are storing an image from resources along with some strings in one array which means the array is `Object`.  I like the idea of storing all the little pieces together, but there is another concern...

You want to be sure those references to `My.Resources.fontname` run once only. Every time that code runs it is creating a *new image object*.  If you arent checking and disposing of old ones, your app will leak (The list from a previous question was much longer).

```
' form/class level declaration
Private FontImgs As Image()
```

Elsewhere to initialize:

```
' build it only once
If FontImgs Is Nothing Then
    FontImgs = New Image() {My.Resources.Arial, My.Resources.Calibri,
                            My.Resources.Segoe, My.Resources.Verdana}
End If

Dim myFonts As New List(Of FontItem)

Dim data = {{"Arial", "arial.ttf", "arialbd.ttf"},
           {"Calibri", "Calibri.ttf", "Calibri.ttf"},
           {"Segoe", "Segoe.ttf", "Segoe.ttf"},
           {"Verdana", "verdana.ttf", "verdanab.ttf"}
           }

For n As Int32 = 0 To FontImgs.Length - 1
    myFonts.Add(New FontItem(FontImgs(n), data(n, 1), data(n, 2), data(n, 0)))
Next

cboFonts.DataSource = myFonts
cboFonts.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

If you initialize the list an array somewhere close to each other, it will be easy to make sure the Image references are in the same order as the rest of the font data.  By the way, your code is passing the Name as the FontFile - the order to the constructor seems incorrect.

- Create the images with a Transparent BG
- Make them all the same size but only as large as needed for the longest of them (minimize white space)
- There is no need to add items to the control, just use your list as the `DataSource`

If this is on a Dialog form that gets re-visited, either be sure to dispose of the images in that array, or make it an app level object that is passed to the form.

For the CBO:

- OwnerDraw = Fixed
- ItemHeight = Height of the images.  Mine are all 179w x 28h, so I used 28
- DropDownHeight to some multiple of the image height plus a margin. Example: 95 allows 3 images to show before the scroll bar appears.
- DropDownWidth to accommodate the image width plus a bit; I used 190
- The Text portion of the control will follow the item size to allow you to draw the selected Item there.  I am letting it print the "Name" (`DisplayMember') there but I set the font size to 14 make use of the space

Once it is set up, add some code to the `DrawItem` event:

```
Private Sub cboFonts_DrawItem(sender As Object, 
            e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cboFonts.DrawItem

    ' no item, early exit
    If e.Index < 0 Then Return

    e.DrawBackground()
    ' get the image from the cbo.fiontitem.imageprop
    Dim img = DirectCast(cboFonts.Items(e.Index), FontItem).TTImageFile

    ' size of the image
    Dim rect = New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y,
                                img.Width, img.Height)
    ' draw it
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, rect)

    e.DrawFocusRectangle()

End Sub
```

[image]

I think I used a too large Font for the images, but you get the idea.  You *can* shrink the images a little by using a `rect` smaller than the actual size (thumbnailing them), but it may not scale as well as actually using a smaller font/image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the lesson, I'm getting error "value of type bitmap cannot be converted to image" on the line "FontImgs = New Image() {My.Resources.arial} On my case, the file arial is a png file, do I need to use another format?

Comment: Thats odd (BitMap inherits from Image) and mine are all PNG too.   using `Bitmap()` instead should work, if not quadruple check that they are actually PNGs (kind of sounds like maybe they are not).  Just because that is the extension doesnt mean thats what they are.

Comment: Changing "Private FontImgs As Image()" to "Private FontImgs As Bitmap()" VisualStudio also makes me change the line to "FontImgs = CType((New Image() {My.Resources.arial, My.Resources.courier, My.Resources.verdana}), Bitmap())"

Now I don't have any error but the combox is displayed with blanks instead of the images. I will try to do all again from zero.

Comment: `Private FontImgs As Bitmap()` and then `FontImgs = New Bitmap() {My.Resources.arial, ...}`  you were supposed to change Image() in both places.  But yes, I think there is something wrong with the image files.  Be sure to add them (PNG with transparent BG) to resources (project properties -> Resources) not just add them to the Resources *folder*.  You can drop them onto that page in VS from File Explorer

Comment: Working now! The line "FontImgs = New Bitmap()" solved the problem. Also I changed the declarations on "Public Class FontItem" changing from Image to Bitmap. Thanks a lot. Allways learning from you.

Comment: I think it is how you added them to the project.  There is a Bitmap image type which is different from JPG TIFF or PNG.  For some reason your project thinks they are actual Bitmaps.  That would bother me because they arent and BMP doesnt support transparency.